# Python win32serviceutil QueryServiceStatus: What does the return value mean?

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I am learning to use pywin32, and am trying to use the win32serviceutil modules on 64bit Python 3.6.4

The following code:

```
import win32serviceutil as service
serviceStatus = service.QueryServiceStatus("WinDefend")
print(serviceStatus)
```

Returns the following tuple:

```
(16, 4, 197, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

I am utterly new to the windows api and pywin32, what does these 6 values mean? Any documentation on pywin32 and win32 isn't revealing anything.

Edit - I'm running Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you got [`SERVICE_STATUS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685996(v=vs.85).aspx) structure

the concrete values mean next:

```
dwServiceType=SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS(16)
dwCurrentState=SERVICE_RUNNING(4)
dwControlsAccepted=SERVICE_ACCEPT_SESSIONCHANGE|SERVICE_ACCEPT_POWEREVENT|SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN|SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP (0xc5==197)
dwWin32ExitCode=NO_ERROR (0)
dwServiceSpecificExitCode=0 // This value is ignored because dwWin32ExitCode != ERROR_SERVICE_SPECIFIC_ERROR.
dwCheckPoint=0
dwWaitHint=0
```

Answer (score 0):

*win32serviceutil* is part of  [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32), which is a *Python* wrapper over *WINAPI*s.

- [[ActiveState.Docs]: win32service.QueryServiceStatus](https://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/win32service__QueryServiceStatus_meth.html) (this is the closest that I could find of an official *PyWin32* doc) is an wrapper over [[MS.Docs]: QueryServiceStatus function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-queryservicestatus) and returns an [[ActiveState.Docs]: SERVICE_STATUS Object](https://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/SERVICE_STATUS.html) (tuple)

  > ```
  > Items:
  > [0] int : serviceType
  >         The type of service.
  > [1] int : serviceState
  >         The current state of the service.
  > [2] int : controlsAccepted
  >         The controls the service accepts.
  > [3] int : win32ExitCode
  >         The win32 error code for the service.
  > [4] int : serviceSpecificErrorCode
  >         The service specific error code.
  > [5] int : checkPoint
  >         The checkpoint reported by the service.
  > [6] int : waitHint
  >         The wait hint reported by the service.
  > ```
- `win32serviceutil.QueryServiceStatus` is a shorthand over the previous (it encapsulates all the other involved calls: `win32service.OpenSCManager`, `win32service.OpenService`, `win32service.CloseServiceHandle`) and returns the same thing