# How can I check if a task in another program is done?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, automation

I'm experimenting a bit with automating things for my work and one of the things I want to try is automating virus scans.

Basically what i'm trying to do is do something after a program (malwarebytes) is done scanning. My first thought was to get a list of the processes on the pc and check if they're running or not but it turns out that anti virus programs don't start an external process as I had hoped.

So now i'm kind of at a loss to be honest.

I'm open to any and all ideas.

The OS is Windows.

An example would be

```
if VirusScanDone():
    print("The scan is all done!")
```

Comment: Can you give an example input and expected output

Comment: I think doing this will depend greatly on the OS being used, so we need to know one are you using. Please tag your question according.

Comment: @martineau 
I edited the post. It's solely windows :)

Comment: @ManojNirale I don't quite follow what you mean by example input/output. I basically want to check if the virus scan is done then do something if it is. I'll just use a while loop with some time.sleep to check it at a fixed interval.

Comment: Check if your AV provider exposes a service (many do), and then you can call the [`QueryServiceStatus` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851473/python-win32serviceutil-queryservicestatus-what-does-the-return-value-mean) to check the status. Usually, on a scan, it would start and then stop. You can also manually trigger the scan on the file (again, based on the AV engine) and then wait for the process to stop. Since you'll be launching the scanner - this would be a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/), get your process name and check if it's running
Example:

```
import psutil
def test_process(procname):
    for p in psutil.process_iter():
        if p.name() == procname:
            print(p.name(),"running")
            test_process(procname)
            break

test_process("PDFXEdit.exe")
```

I've tested with pdfeditor app you can do this on your antivirus software process name

Comment: Thanks for the idea but i've already tried this. As I mentioned in my question anti virus programs don't seem to start an external process from the main program. So unfortunately it doesn't seem like going through the processes in the task manager works.